# How do I install tkinter on Python 3.6 on Debian?

Tags: python, tkinter, debian, apt-get

My partner decided to use Debian for our dedicated server, whereas I am more of an Arch Linux person. But alas, people online recommended Debian to him so we ended up using that.

The issue is: some of our projects use `matplotlib`, which requires `tkinter`. However, this package was NOT installed when we installed `python3.6` using apt-get.

A few google searches recommended `apt-get install python3-tk`, but this installed `tkinter` for `python3.4`, which Debian came with (which is odd to me as 3.6 is fairly standard these days).

As `python3.6-tk` was not listed, I decided to ask for help in here.

Comment: python3.6 -m pip install tkinter????

Comment: @Coinbase1031tkinter is standard library and thus not on pypi

Comment: how did you install `python3-6` ? If you will install from source code then it should compile and install with tkinter - eventually it will need to install `tcl/tk` which is use by tkinter.

Comment: we installed it with `apt-get install python3.6` I think, and it didn't require that. `tcl/tk` is not even installed....

Comment: `tkinter` is wrapper for language `tcl` and its graphics module `tk`. `tkinter` doesn't display windows/widgets directly but it executes `tcl/tk` commands to do it

Comment: BTW: what error message do you get when you try to use tkinter in code ?

Comment: `import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk`

EDIT: apparently it was built from source instead of apt

Comment: I added the source tgz into /opt/python36x, md5summed and checked, extracted, and followed the typical instructions in Readme.rst. In 3.6.2. My command history doesn't show any doubt related with tkinter and i am sure it's the 2nd thing I test after installing. Unless I had installed manually some missing lib for an older version of python3 (that would be no longer in my history)